# Micronaut 1.0 RC1 does not run in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, micronaut

I have created a blank app using Micronaut 1.0.RC1 and CLI command

```
mn create-app sillynaut --profile service \
   --features java,spock,jdbc-hikari,hibernate-jpa,jib
```

After importing the project into IntelliJ 2018.2.4 I tried to start the Application by running the main method of the `Application` class.

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java "-javaagent:/Users/saw303/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/182.4505.22/IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2 EAP.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=58014:/Users/saw303/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/182.4505.22/IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2 EAP.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/saw303/dev/private/sillynaut/out/production/classes:/Users/saw303/dev/private/sillynaut/out/production/resources:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.micronaut/http-client/1.0.0.RC1/e0fc1145ac279e2cb37ba83588de3c0deb7f5562/http-client-1.0.0.RC1.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.micronaut.configuration/hibernate-jpa/1.0.0.RC1/5f7482f9c8dfde45d9c0e5ddfb743af22e9ccc64/hibernate-jpa-1.0.0.RC1.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.micronaut.configuration/hibernate-validator/1.0.0.RC1/505c233c19409a644fd519308741a020610c8755/hibernate-validator-1.0.0.RC1.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.micronaut/validation/1.0.0.RC1/9f489bc12364c0a5b647e7538f8be830f7849bdb/validation-1.0.0.RC1.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.micronaut/http-server-netty/1.0.0.RC1/20bfb981de34fc9b32aae83b7141ac8b139c673b/http-server-netty-1.0.0.RC1.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.micronaut/http-server/1.0.0.RC1/8c1d1b42691a41e81a006049a363ff29014ce8cb/http-server-1.0.0.RC1.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.micronaut/runtime/1.0.0.RC1/f9fa101c607f9fcb77c4b4d761873002d28edff3/runtime-1.0.0.RC1.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.micronaut.configuration/jdbc-hikari/1.0.0.RC1/1ce15a9884df1887301adf12e484722cf332c5c1/jdbc-hikari-1.0.0.RC1.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.micronaut/http-netty/1.0.0.RC1/ca6338005bda1be53f0b502ae43ce7be708beab0/http-netty-1.0.0.RC1.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.micronaut/websocket/1.0.0.RC1/e36ee91ebd54fca37b04abd12b724aaa54e0e82d/websocket-1.0.0.RC1.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.micronaut/router/1.0.0.RC1/b6d9b9788c8c7aa6d6574765b4025478ada0a21f/router-1.0.0.RC1.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.micronaut/http/1.0.0.RC1/594776dec6ea851bf0991586f68a642dfe327cfe/http-1.0.0.RC1.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.micronaut/spring/1.0.0.RC1/a690ca8cdc8171c0951ae361329a105b2297e0cf/spring-1.0.0.RC1.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.micronaut/aop/1.0.0.RC1/de6aacbc752eb66d16cb55f67e82136802c397a6/aop-1.0.0.RC1.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.micronaut/jdbc/1.0.0.RC1/38ba150513d5e2cc8b480d6f21cc46b339acbdc2/jdbc-1.0.0.RC1.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.3.2/934c04d3cfef185a8008e7bf34331b79730a9d43/javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.micronaut/buffer-netty/1.0.0.RC1/52d8abe4b92041ec14028e1523c02cb917943b48/buffer-netty-1.0.0.RC1.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mariadb.jdbc/mariadb-java-client/2.2.5/3d1406a8ed02ca69cc389ae715cee8913871a81e/mariadb-java-client-2.2.5.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.zaxxer/HikariCP/2.7.9/a83113d2c091d0d0f853dad3217bd7df3beb6ae3/HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/7c4f3c474fb2c041d8028740440937705ebb473a/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.25/da76ca59f6a57ee3102f8f9bd9cee742973efa8a/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.reactivex.rxjava2/rxjava/2.2.2/db2277cb0641bd8bd2f491fab555d37345351d6/rxjava-2.2.2.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-handler-proxy/4.1.29.Final/67e9473ac043b4d173ac9d620d43eb428ecc408a/netty-handler-proxy-4.1.29.Final.jar:/Users/saw303/.m2/repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.23/ec62d74fe50689c28c0ff5b35d3aebcaa8b5be68/snakeyaml-1.23.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator/6.0.13.Final/af4232bf90ecd33c71147d67185dbb1cfe8f33df/hibernate-validator-6.0.13.Final.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.validation/validation-api/2.0.1.Final/cb855558e6271b1b32e716d24cb85c7f583ce09e/validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.9.7/98d8f190db07f97c64c0ea3af5792f718a6c2cc1/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.7.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.9.7/cbd919f1ce67533e07b98dd493247e8dbabc26b2/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.7.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.7/e6faad47abd3179666e89068485a1b88a195ceb7/jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.3.6.Final/42c7130757c3f67dda008d8edb28b381a09a7ce6/hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-orm/5.0.8.RELEASE/4da63072d1ed6a2eb4bc0a4c8da5e09f39b5021e/spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.reactivestreams/reactive-streams/1.0.1/1b1c911686eb40179219466e6a59b634b9d7a748/reactive-streams-1.0.1.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-codec-http/4.1.29.Final/454688b88cea27a4d407202d1fc79a6522345b5e/netty-codec-http-4.1.29.Final.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-handler/4.1.29.Final/1acf1d94799296a2517533ec75ce7e155e9c4ea7/netty-handler-4.1.29.Final.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-codec-socks/4.1.29.Final/f687150259de44f0ff7b37a449f1a1bf6f20e992/netty-codec-socks-4.1.29.Final.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/1.2.3/864344400c3d4d92dfeb0a305dc87d953677c03c/logback-core-1.2.3.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-codec/4.1.29.Final/1651bc2e279216773c234cafe402d68d2a5adc90/netty-codec-4.1.29.Final.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-transport/4.1.29.Final/c190b90f70e2ae8a48c068afad709e8728fcaa39/netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305/3.0.2/25ea2e8b0c338a877313bd4672d3fe056ea78f0d/jsr305-3.0.2.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.9.0/7c10d545325e3a6e72e06381afe469fd40eb701/jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.9.7/4b7f0e0dc527fab032e9800ed231080fdc3ac015/jackson-core-2.9.7.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate.common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.0.4.Final/965a18fdf939ee75e41f7918532d37b3a8350535/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.4.Final.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging/3.3.2.Final/3789d00e859632e6c6206adc0c71625559e6e3b0/jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api/2.2/25665ac8c0b62f50e6488173233239120fc52c96/javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javassist/javassist/3.23.1-GA/c072c13dcb7f705471c40bafb1536171df850ab2/javassist-3.23.1-GA.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.8.17/9a36bc0f6eb9f941da0526ad89c4fb4b8ab580f0/byte-buddy-1.8.17.jar:/Users/saw303/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec/1.1.1.Final/a8485cab9484dda36e9a8c319e76b5cc18797b58/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.1.1.Final.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jboss/jandex/2.0.5.Final/7060f67764565b9ee9d467e3ed0cb8a9c601b23a/jandex-2.0.5.Final.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml/classmate/1.3.4/3d5f48f10bbe4eb7bd862f10c0583be2e0053c6/classmate-1.3.4.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.activation/javax.activation-api/1.2.0/85262acf3ca9816f9537ca47d5adeabaead7cb16/javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/5d3ccc056b6f056dbf0dddfdf43894b9065a8f94/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/5.0.8.RELEASE/efcf5f0ccaaa9deec2d9133c9d6bfbb7e55370ff/spring-jdbc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-tx/5.0.8.RELEASE/b6488db6192f71bd682a13b9d42127307631c616/spring-tx-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-context/5.0.8.RELEASE/3a067d8990761111c9b6d1d895640be26cc1fb38/spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-aop/5.0.8.RELEASE/f5086c1a3185c481104511837427b39a07a57aa2/spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-beans/5.0.8.RELEASE/5fc965d3e7f5515099244857a8ae9e2a208c169b/spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-expression/5.0.8.RELEASE/f23158f22c917df2cddf2ecebc398a9e95f95fae/spring-expression-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-core/5.0.8.RELEASE/dc39c49e3246cdf73d3786ac41119140aed3fa08/spring-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish/javax.el/3.0.1-b08/8fa39d3901fc6ec8c0fff4ad4e48c26c4911c422/javax.el-3.0.1-b08.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-buffer/4.1.29.Final/c3809f72e4b535b343b7dfa3c0c8210dad2fa5ea/netty-buffer-4.1.29.Final.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-resolver/4.1.29.Final/bbec1dc913732e4773893c14d795b15d6c1e878e/netty-resolver-4.1.29.Final.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-jcl/5.0.8.RELEASE/a1fa8fb560fb252321776e16bc9ac8201af4ef5e/spring-jcl-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:/Users/saw303/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-common/4.1.29.Final/a5d6a735ed07d8f197daa48db7f097cfc971ee5e/netty-common-4.1.29.Final.jar sillynaut.Application
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/micronaut/context/ApplicationContextBuilder
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sillynaut.Application.main(Application.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.micronaut.context.ApplicationContextBuilder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 13 more
```

Running it with from the console using `./gradlew run` works fine.

This is the content of `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.6.RELEASE"
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "4.0.0"
    id "net.ltgt.apt-eclipse" version "0.18"
    id "net.ltgt.apt-idea" version "0.18"
    id "com.google.cloud.tools.jib" version "0.9.9" 
}

apply plugin:"application"
apply plugin:"java"
apply plugin:"groovy"

version "0.1"
group "sillynaut"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com" }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'io.micronaut:bom:1.0.0.RC1'
    }
}

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor "io.micronaut:inject-java"
    annotationProcessor "io.micronaut:validation"
    annotationProcessor "javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:2.2"
    implementation "io.micronaut:http-client"
    implementation "io.micronaut:inject"
    implementation "io.micronaut:validation"
    implementation "io.micronaut:runtime"
    implementation "io.micronaut.configuration:jdbc-hikari"
    implementation "io.micronaut.configuration:hibernate-jpa"
    implementation "io.micronaut:http-server-netty"
    implementation "javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2"
    compileOnly "io.micronaut:inject-java"
    runtimeOnly "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3"

    testImplementation("org.spockframework:spock-core:1.2-groovy-2.4") {
        exclude group: "org.codehaus.groovy", module: "groovy-all"
    }
    testImplementation "io.micronaut:inject-groovy"
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"
    testImplementation "io.micronaut:inject-java"
    testImplementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3"

    runtime 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:2.2.5'
}

shadowJar {
    mergeServiceFiles()
}

run.jvmArgs('-noverify', '-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1')

mainClassName = "sillynaut.Application"
compileJava.options.compilerArgs += '-parameters'
compileTestJava.options.compilerArgs += '-parameters'
jib.to.image = 'gcr.io/sillynaut/jib-image'
```

I managed to workaround the issue by changing the dependency scope of `io.micronaut:inject` from `implementation` to `compile`. But I was wondering why the CLI generates dependencies using scope of Gradles `java-library` plugin but only applies the Gradle `java` plugin.

Since IntelliJ is usually very good in setting the dependency scopes I was wondering if this is a bug. Can anyone confirm or explain this?

Comment: Please report an issue to the issue tracker: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues

Comment: Raised issue https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/685

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you enable the annotation processors.
in **Intelij**:
File > Setting > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > annotation processors then enable it

Comment: Has nothing to do with the annotation processing. It's a Gradle / Intellij issue. Annotation processing in IDEA was enabled